# chmod() a directory on localhost

Tags: localhost, chmod

I'm currently trying out an upload form for .csv files on localhost, however I haven't been able to upload a file with it yet. This is because I need to chmod a directory on localhost. Currently I'm using this:

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.csv');
$max_filesize = 524288;
$upload_path = '/csvfiles/';

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

// Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.

if(!is_writable($upload_path)){
 $chmod = chmod ($upload_path & "/" & $_FILES, 777);

 // Upload the file to your specified path.
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)){
    echo 'Upload succesful';
    }else{
    echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again. :('; // It failed :(.
         }
    } else
    die ('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD the directory.');
```

I'm not sure what this line of code needs to be:

```
$chmod = chmod ($upload_path & "/" & $_FILES, 777);
```

My script keeps dying, and nothing happens to the directory.

Also, if you have experience with these kind of things, feel free to debug! :D

```
Side note: My OS is RHEL5
```

Thanks in advance,

-Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate the `$_FILES` array to a string to create the final path to be `chmod`ded and that's probably the problem. If I understand this correctly, you need to change this to:

```
$chmod = chmod ($upload_path & "/" & $filename, 777);
```

or

```
$chmod = chmod ($upload_path & "/" & $_FILES['userfile']['name'], 777);
```

so you append the *file name*  to `$upload_path`.

Answer (score 3):

1) Check that its already writable
2) If it is not, use exec() to chmod.

```
if(!is_writable($path)) {
    exec("chmod -R 777 $path");
} 

// code for uploading.
```

This code can be made far prettier for example wrapping it into a recursive function but I will leave that upto you :)

- This information is based on you actually having permissions to chmod a directory.